# WPF C# Vertical Scrollbar always visible by docking at a DockPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, stackpanel, dockpanel

I have a problem with my vertical scrollbar.

If I scroll the Content with my horizontal bar, I see the vertical bar at the end of my Scrolling.

First I see this:

[image]

After Scrolling I see this:

[image]

I am looking for a solution to always see both bars!

### Panel structure

```
Scrollviewer : Horizontical
     Dockpanel : Content
          Dockpanel : left
          Scrollviewer : Vertical 
               Dockpanel right
                   Stackpanel : columns....
```

Code:

```
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="scv_dpn_variable"
                    CanContentScroll="True"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    Height="auto"
                    Width="auto"
                    Margin="15,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="spn_right"  VerticalAlignment="Top">

                        <DockPanel x:Name="dpn_right_header" Width="auto" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Label Content="Jan" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Feb" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Mrz" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Apr" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Mai" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Jun" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Jul" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Aug" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="45" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Sep" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Okt" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Nov" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="45" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>
                            <Label Content="Dez" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="40" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>

                            <Label Content="Bemerkung" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="300" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="18"/>

                        </DockPanel>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scv_content_Vert1"                      
        Height="auto"
        MaxHeight="550"

        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        Width="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollChanged="scv_content_Vert1_ScrollChanged" UseLayoutRounding="False" CanContentScroll="True"

                  >
                        <DockPanel x:Name="dpn_right_content" Width="auto" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_jan"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_feb"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_mrz"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_apr"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_mai"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_jun"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_jul"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_aug"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_sep"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_okt"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_nov"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_dez"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel x:Name="spn_col_notice"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                        </DockPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

the whole code!. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please post the whole code.

Comment: I have been edit my post! Thanks

Comment: Isn't this expected behaviour? You want to be able to see (and use) the vertical scroll bar no matter how you've scrolled horizontally (and vice versa).

Comment: But you have this - `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` in your ScrollViewer definition. Shouldn't this be "Auto"?